# Will the High-Level Synthesis (HLS) design approach for FPGAs reduce the demand for RTL designers?

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, software, hdl, rtl

I'm a senior electrical engineering student who's very interested in FPGAs and RTL design. But recently after learning what HLS compilers are capable of I had to consider the possibility that eventually the majority of RTL design will be done by computer science gurus using high level languages which will reduce the demand for RTL design specialists.

I understand that the need for experts in hardware description languages will never completely disappear as long and FPGAs still exist, so my question would be is it reasonable to think that the need for RTL/FPGA designers will be significantly reduced by the growing mainstream commercialization of HLS design tools?

Answer (score 3):

Eventually, the compiler more or less wiped out the assembly programmer. But it took a long time, and there are still a few paid ones about, optimising high speed functions to the Nth. There are more hobby ones about, doing it the hard way for the fun of it.

Eventually, HLS will more or less wipe out the RTL level designer. But it will take a long time, and there will still be a few paid ones about ...

Comment: Optimization is combinatorially expensive. But "compilers" slowly become smarter, as more and more tricks are embedded into the optimization phase of the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

At the very least, people involved in development of those HLS tools will have to know how they work and thus understand RTL in details. Just like with general programming nowadays, when you have assembler guys in each compiler/HAL/System library team.

Even for regular HW designers, the knowledge of RTL will be a big plus. How will you debug your HLS code which doesn't work as you expect, if you don't understand the concept it is based on? Again, this is the same as with software, where programmers who have no idea of assembly can be completely blocked during debugging when they see a variable with no address or a breakpoint inside an inlined or partially merged function which triggers "for no reason".

Answer (score 2):

As long as performance is resource constrained, understanding the lower level functionality of the hardware and coding to deal with its idiosyncrasies will always produce more efficient and thus more cost effective solutions.

If an application can tolerate area, speed, and/or cost penalties, then HLS solutions may be sufficient.  Except for low volume applications, I think it will be a long time before the efficiency of a design can be ignored, so the market for knowledgeable HDL designers is not going away any time soon.  Those who understand the lower level functionality can also command a higher salary.

Answer (score 2):

In C and assembly programming, if you want to optimize code and make it run as fast as possible, code is hand optimized for the architecture of the CPU and its pipeline. The code is even optimized for cache sizes on CPU's. Even traversing arrays can be optimized for cache loading strategies. While we have less machine code programmers, they are still necessary.

The same goes for RTL\FPGA designers, if you want your RTL to be optimized, you will need a designer that can understand FPGA architecture a on a high level. An RTL designer can hand optimize designs, which a computer won't have that ability because they don't have the connectivity and understand ideas like humans do.

Answer (score 1):

I personally believe we are heading in the direction of higher level coding, being that parts are growing in orders of magnitudes (in resources, that is).

But I think your job will be safe for awhile, and here's why: Compilers eventually made assembly programmers go extinct, but it took quite some time. FPGAs are generally in much less demand than software, so I believe this will scale down the number of people/resources being poured into this effort of making this higher level coding possible.